# Problem trying to write a simple html page to play speech when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very beginner to JavaScript and HTML but I am trying to write a page to say speech when buttons are pressed. There are two buttons and problem is that both buttons say the same speech and not the speech assigned to its 'words' variable.

```html
<body>
  <button id="button" onclick="speak()">click for greeting</button>
  <script>
  var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  synth.onvoiceschanged = setVoices;
  var words = 'How are you?';
  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(words);


    function speak () {
      synth.speak(utterThis, voices);
  }

  function setVoices () {  
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    utterThis.voice = voices[77];
  }
  </script>

<button id="button2" onclick="speak()">click for reply</button>
  <script>
  var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  synth.onvoiceschanged = setVoices;
  var wordsGrievous = 'I am fine.';
  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(wordsGrievous);


  function speak () {
    synth.speak(utterThis, voices);
  }

  function setVoices () {  
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    utterThis.voice = voices[77];
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="speak(1)">click for greeting</button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="speak(2)">click for reply</button>
 
    <script>
    
        var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
        synth.onvoiceschanged = setVoices;
        var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

        function speak (words) {
            var words1 = 'How are you?';
            var words2 = 'I am fine.';

            switch (words){
                case 1: utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(words1); break;
                case 2: utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(words2);
            }
            synth.speak(utterThis, voices);
        }

        function setVoices () {  
          voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
          utterThis.voice = voices[77];
        }
    </script>
</body>
```